# Azure B2C Authentication (angular + .net core Web API) - Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token

Tags: c#, angular, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

i try to do an angular application with MSAL-angular and Azure B2C for authentication.
I am able to authenticate the angular app with Azure B2C (i have create a susi flow) and obtain the token as show in image below

[image: Token aquisition]

so i have create a .net core web api project and modify the appsetting configuration and the start up with this code :

appsetting.json :

```
    "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://{mytenat}.b2clogin.com/tfp",
    "ClientId": "8xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxc",
    "Domain": "{mytenat}.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_susi"
  }
```

startup.cs

```
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
                    {
                        Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                        options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
                        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                    },
                    options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });

            // By default, the claims mapping will map claim names in the old format to accommodate older SAML applications.
            //'http://schemas.microsodt.com/ws/2008/06/identity/clains/role' instead of 'roles'
            // This flag ensures that the ClaimsIdentity claims collection will be build from the claims in the token
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
            //services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            //{
            //    // The claim in the Jwt token where App roles are available.
            //    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
            //});
```

but if i try to run localy the project and call it with postman i have this error :

**System.UnauthorizedAccessException: IDW10201: Neither scope or roles claim was found in the bearer token. **

i don't understand where is the error.
can you help me?

thanks

Comment: This should be related to your `scope`. Are you using delegated permissions?

Comment: What are your `consentScopes`? That is, the `scope` of the administrator consent.

Comment: Got any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you have created a web api application and angular app in Azure AD B2C. Next, you need to **expose** the api of the web api application, and then add permissions to the angular app.

First go to web api.

[image]

Then go to angular app>API permissions> add a permission>My APIs>your web api app.

[image]

Finally, when you parse the token, you will see the `scp:access` claim.

Comment: If there is no two different API and Client apps, then in that case? I am facing the same error